# slideUP div after css background image loads

Tags: jquery, css, image, background, preload

I have a page that I am trying to achieve 2 things
- 3d effect on using css, background images, and z-index
- sliding div using Jquery to make movie type credits roll up the screen.

http://titanstudio.net/about.html

I have tried several jquery image preloaders that I found on various posts but none seem to work, im assuming because they are css background images.  The issue I am having is on first load, the foreground image is not loading quick enough (it is a rather large png) and the credits start rolling up the page over top of the background image.  Of course when you reload the page, it works fine since the images are cached, and the credit text correctly scrolls up the screen in between background and foreground images.

My question:  Is there a way to delay the credits scrolling up the screen until after the foreground image loads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add this?
The code inside is executed after the page is fully loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
  //scroll up here
});
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy enough.  I really need to brush up on my jquery.  I had document.ready which I thought meant the page was loaded.  Thanks Greg.